# Select sum some column with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL table like this

| id | date | number | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-02-02 | 1 | DC |
| 2 | 2022-02-03 | 20 | DC |
| 3 | 2022-02-03 | 9 | DC |
| 4 | 2022-03-04 | 2 | KF |

I want to sum number column with condition "type" = "DC" and last row per date.
I should get result 10 (9+1) because on date 2022-02-03 have 2 row, the last row will taken (9)

Comment: So what's stopping you doing what you need to do? What is the difficulty you are having achieving your goal? What have you tried? Why isn't it working? What about the articles/documentation/answers you read didn't you understand?

Answer (score -1):

First we have to get ids that respect your conditions (type = 'DC' and max id ):

```
select type, max(id) as id
  from mytable
  where type = 'DC'
  group by type, date
```

Then we join this list with our table to get the whole row :

```
select sum(number)
from mytable t
join (
  select type, max(id) as id
  from mytable
  where type = 'DC'
  group by type, date
) as s on s.id = t.id
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/cYAUCkEA)